# Order of modular group

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove $|(\mathbb{Z} / p^e \mathbb{Z} )^{\times}| = p^e - p^{e-1}$
I know it has something to do with the fact that we have $p^e$ elements and we're substracting $p^{e-1}$ multiples of $p$, but I'd like to know how to formally prove this.

Comment: It should be $(\mathbb{Z}/p^e\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, and its just $\varphi(p^e)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. First show that in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, the residue class $\bar{a} \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is invertible if and only if $\gcd(a,n) = 1$. Edit: Here is the argument.

Suppose $\gcd(a,n) = 1$. Then there exists $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ax + ny = 1$. Now look at this equation in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. There it says that $\bar{a}\bar{x} + \bar{0} = \bar{1}$. By definition, this says that $\bar{a}$ is invertible.

For the converse, suppose that there exists $\bar{x} \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\bar{a}\bar{x} = \bar{1}$. Let $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ be any integer whose residue class is $\bar{x}$. Then the equation $\bar{a} \cdot \bar{x} = \bar{1}$ says that $ax = 1 + ny$ for some $y \in \mathbb{Z}$. Of course, this says that $ax -ny = 1$ which in turn implies that $\gcd(a,n) = 1$.

Now note that $\gcd(p^e, a) = 1$ if and only if $p \nmid a$. Your claim now follows.

Comment: why is $\bar{a}$ invertible iff $\operatorname{gcd} (a,n) =1$?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter This follows from Bézout's lemma.

Comment: @Marie Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Marie define invertible in this case

Comment: @AnthonyPeter: I've edited the post to include this argument in detail.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter: One more edit simplifying part of the argument.